# GDAL compilation to .NET (C#) use

Tags: c#, c++, .net, gis, gdal

I want compile GDAL library to use in C# program. I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. Before, I compiled GDAL C++, as result I have dlls and libraries (No problems) . Next I try compile with [instruction](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrCsharpCompile), because I want use GDAL in C# program. But, I don't understate what should I do in this step.

> **Creating the SWIG interface code**
>   For creating the interface execute the following command.
>
> `nmake /f makefile.vc interface`
>
> Previous Step make's error when regenerates the *PINVOKE.cs files ,so
>   skip to next step ,it will work

I try skip this step, but always have the same exception (show below). As result I don't have dlls to use in C#...

```
    ogr\OsrPINVOKE.cs(192,10): error CS0111: Type 'OSGeo.OGR.OsrPINVOKE' already
        defines a member called 'OsrPINVOKE' with the same parameter types
ogr\OsrPINVOKE.cs(188,10): (Location of symbol related to previous error)
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\csc.EXE"' :
 return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

What should I compile GDAL to C#? Maybe you have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find compiled binaries at http://www.gisinternals.com/

Just add reference to \bin\gdal\csharp*_csharp.dll, add *_wrap.dll to your output location and other gdal dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated definition of class constructed function in GdalPINVOKE.cs, OgrPINVOKE.cs, OsrPINVOKE.cs.

Just comment out the repeated lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the nuget package, if you install GDAL Native to your project you will get all the dll's you need and some configuration .cs so that you can call the libraries with no need to import them on your .cs